# Refresh text EditText after finish()

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I created a 'New File' activity using

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewFile.class),1);
```

The NewFile activity lets users set certain options for their text file then after clicking a button a string is saved to a static variable in my StringBuilder class and finish(); is called. How can I load this new string into the MainActivity's EditText? onCreate() is only called when the activity is first created right?

Comment: Since you're using `startActivityForResult()`, you don't need static variables, just have `NewFile` Load up an Intent with the data then in the calling Activity's `onActivityResult()` get the Text and set it. More work, but it's the proper way to handle data transfer between Activities.

Answer (score 1):

Do it on onResume or onActivityResult. It would be ideal though onActivityResult since you've used startActivityForResult, before finishing the other activity you set the setResult(int resultCode, Intent data) if you have intent to sent back or if none setResult(int resultCode). I think it is better to put the string which will be used to update your EditText as extra in the intent, then set the text using that string in onActivityResult method.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        et.setText(DocumentBuilder.docText);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

in your class `NewFile.java` :

```
String strName = "toto";
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("name", "toto");
setResult(1, intent);
finish();
```

in your `MainActivity.java` :

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
          // Handle successful result
          String name  = intent.getStringExtra("name");
          editText.setText(name);
      }
    }
}
```

refer this [tutorial](http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/12204/onactivityresult-android-tutorial/) for more explanations